# Combining two arrays into one in Python, by dynamic allocation

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays, `list_string` & `list_string2`. Their values are assigned and filled statically(In the editor)

```
list_string = ["1", "12", "15", "21", "131"]

#DEFINING THE ROW AND COLUMN VALUE FOR RESULTANT ARRAY
rows,coln = (5,5)

#INITIALIZING THE RESULTANT ARRAY
arr = [[0]for i in range(rows) for j in range(coln)]

list_string2 = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

#ITERATING THROUGH EACH OF THE LISTS FOR FILLING
for i in range(len(list_string)):
     for j in range(len(list_string2)):
         arr[i][j] = [list_string[i]] [list_string2[j]])
```

I did some reading, seeing other threads on defining, Initializing 2D arrays, but all of them create new arrays and statically assign the values. I'm trying to dynamically assign the values but
the error code, I'm getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:......intro2.py", line 12, in 
>       arr.append([list_string[i]] [list_2[j]])  TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

The indices i & j being used are definitely integers, since they are looping through the range method. Can anyone explain why this is happening.

**EDIT 2:**

*Expected Output:*

> [ ["1"  "1"  "12"  "15"  "21"  "131"]
>
> ["2 "  "1"  "12"  "15"  "21"  "131"]
>
> ["3" " 1"  "12"  "15" ........"131"]
>
> ["4"  "1" ......................"131"]
>
> ["5"   ........................."131"]

*Code changes:*

I figured out some out of bounds index errors, and modified the code as follows,(Error still persists)

```
    list_string = ["1", "12", "15", "21", "131"]

#DEFINING THE ROW AND COLUMN VALUE FOR RESULTANT ARRAY
rows,coln = (5,6)
arr = [[0 for i in range(coln)] for j in range(rows)]

print(arr)

list_string2 = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

#ITERATING THROUGH EACH OF THE LISTS FOR FILLING
for i in range(len(list_string)):
     for j in range(len(list_string2)):
         arr[i][j] = [list_string[i]][list_string2[j]]


print (arr)
```

Comment: `arr[i][j] = [list_string[i]] [list_string2[j]])` looks incorrect. Your missing a `(` bracket and other things.

Comment: Like a 2d matrix = [ ["0" "1" "12"....."131"]["1" "1" "12".."131"][.....].....]

Comment: @FaizAhmed That doesn't look like a 2D matrix. A 2D matrix would have an extra level and look something like `[["0", "1"], ["12", "13"]]`

Comment: @RoadRunner Where should the ")" be present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**

If I understood correctly, you do not need `rows, coln` variables since the loops depend on the sizes of `list_string` and `list_string2`

```
arr = [list_string[:] for _ in range(len(list_string2))]
for i, l in enumerate(arr): 
   l.insert(0, list_string2[i])
```

This will produce your expected output

```
>>> print(arr)
[['1', '1', '12', '15', '21', '131'],
 ['2', '1', '12', '15', '21', '131'],
 ['3', '1', '12', '15', '21', '131'],
 ['4', '1', '12', '15', '21', '131'],
 ['5', '1', '12', '15', '21', '131']]
```

---

First of all, there is an extra bracket here

```
arr[i][j] = [list_string[i]] [list_string2[j]])
                                              ^
```

To explain the error, it comes from here

```
arr[i][j] = [list_string[i]] [list_string2[j]]
```

`[list_string[i]]` evaluates to a new list with an element from `list_string`. For `i=0`, this is `["1"]`. For `[list_string2[j]]` it is `["1"]` for `j=0`

When you put square brackets after a list, syntactically that is to access an element of the list. So the last line of you code is equivalent to the below

```
lstr = ["1"]            # [list_string[0]]
arr[i][j] = lstr["1"]   # [list_string[0]] [list_string2[0]]
```

You are trying to access element `"1"` of a list which does not make sense. This is why you are getting `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Assigning the 0th index of arr, i.e. arr[0][0],to [list_string[0]] [list_string2[0]] . The square brackets are put, so that value from that indexes can be taken, and can be assigned to arr, which will have the same indexes at one point in the loop.

Comment: If a string value is being assigned to arr, should'nt it consider arr as a list of strings ??

Comment: That is exactly what is wrong here. Your expected outcome is not clear. Update the question with the expected output and I will try to give you a better explanation.

Comment: ,I've Made some changes, it's explained in the edit, I hope its more clear now. Thanks

Comment: You don't have a `0` in your `list_string2` regardless of the first line of your edit

Comment: Oh, I must have lost track of the list, in this jargon. Anyways fixed it, if there are anymore, i hope you point out.